# My tone will be heard to caller

Tags: android, telephony

I need to develop the app like the dialer tone,

The pre-setted tone by me should be heard to caller( the one who calls me).

**For example** , if A calls B , B's tone should be heard to A.

I need to know is it possible or not in android..? And please suggest me some ideas to do this friends.

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I analyzed for similar apps in market to get any idea but those apps are not compatable for my galaxy S.Those similar apps are Bigpond and caller tunes

Comment: any least you tried some codes.

Comment: That only i did't get any ideas yet.I thought it is impossible.Now i need only the ideas friends

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you mean DTMF tones or something similar to that.

The only way you could do this is to create your own modified Android ROM and put that onto a rooted phone. Applications by default are not allowed to send tones over the voice call uplink.
Generating the tone yourself and injecting PCM data into the uplink also wouldn't work, because there's no API in place in Android that allows applications to do that (even though the platform might support it).

Comment: Thanks @Michael for your response..So we cant do anything without rooting our ROM ..?